# Omniture SiteCatalyst: how to keep track of session-drops with an eVar?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I would need to record the value of an eVar only when the session ends.
Thank you,
Marco

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to set a value in an eVar when the visit ends OR do you want to record somewhere else the value in an eVar when a visitors visit ends. Also do you mean session=visit. Thanks C.

Answer (score 1):

a session ends when the session times out (as in, due to user inactivity), when the user leaves the site, or when the user closes the browser.  There is no 100% reliable way to listen or mark any of these events. Your best bet is to populate the `eVar` on every page or activity and set attribution in interface to last value.  But again, this will not reliably give you what you want.